# Flexbox/Grid dependent on child percentage height (Firefox/Edge)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I've been trying to switch from a table layout to something more modern. I have a layout that requires a "fixed" header and a sticky footer. To achieve it, I decided to alter how the page works a little bit by instead of letting the entire page scroll I created a scrolling div as the body/footer area. This keeps the header at the top with a dynamic height while mimicking how the typical page scrolls.

However, I've run into the same issue in both flexbox and grid. I've gotten the layout to work as long as I don't have any child elements that are based on percentage. If there are any, it appears that the flexbox gets resized  in accordance to the child. For instance, if the height of a div within one of the children is set to 100%, it will display the div, but any other content after it is overflowed and the footer appears out of place. This seems a bit counter-intuitive to me, and I was hoping someone could explain the design choice behind it? Are there any workarounds to allow this kind of functionality?

I basically figured that the flexbox system would allow for the filling of remaining space (for the body), but also expand as necessary to enclose all children.

I wrote a quick sample to show what I'm talking about. See below, thanks!

**Edit:** This seems to only happen in Firefox and Edge, not Chrome.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.bg {
  background-color: gray;
}

.span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.flex > .main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="main">
      <ul>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer>
      This should be a sticky footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</div><div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="bg span">
        This breaks the page
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
        <li>This is a spacer</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer>
      This should be a sticky footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using `min-height: 100%;` on the flex item so you are allowing it to overflow, you should probably use `height: 100%;` there

Comment: I'm a bit confused, wouldn't min-height allow the container to expand instead of overflow? I would think that height would cause it to overflow if the height of the contents was greater than 100%?

Comment: yes it will expand but it's parent is having `height:100%` so it will overflow its parent and you won't have overlow inside it because you didn't set a fixed or a max-height .. so the `flex` item will be as bigger as it's content AND overflowing its parent

Comment: What do you expect .span {height: 100%;} do? It's direct parent has no height, so it does nothing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif , that's actually the intended behavior. The problem I'm experiencing is that the flexbox in the second example is not expanding to include the list, thus the footer appears before the list. So, it looks like the list is overflowing the flexbox instead of expanding it.

Comment: You are talking about the demo results on Firefox I guess, as it's totally different on Chrome.

Comment: @Stickers Ah, you're right. I guess this is a browser-specific issue. I didn't realize, thanks. I'll update the question.

Comment: What is the layout you're achieving by the way? why do you need that percentage height inner div?

Comment: Well, the basic layout is sticky header, body, sticky footer. I'm kind of building the frame of a site that's meant to be expanded... So, while I may not be using a 100% div height currently, I did want to support it for the future. Like if someone wanted a full page background and centered content on the page (kind of like Tumblr's home page, but with scrollbars instead). Since the header and footer are dynamic, I can't use a set height easily. I was able to do something similar a while ago with layout tables... And this may be barking up the wrong tree, but I thought I'd ask..

Comment: Does that mean basically on Firefox your demo works fine, and you want it to work the same on Chrome?

Comment: Ah, no, both don't work, but Chrome's implementation is nicer and I could probably work around it. In Firefox/Edge, the flexbox (parent) is resizing to its child, which is really odd. However, it only occurs with percentages. Pixels and/or other scalar values appear to expand the flexbox properly. Chrome just doesn't recognize the height on the parent and thus the child doesn't fill the parent, which I could potentially work around. At this point, I'm just curious as to the issue in the other two browsers...

Comment: Or, I guess, the percentage might be "locking" the flexbox height for some reason?

Comment: You can always use `height:100vh` rather than `height:100%` if needed.

Comment: I did try that, but since the header and footer do produce some height, the div becomes too large to relation to what it should be.. For instance, if the browser is 1000 pixels high, the header is 100 pixels high, footer is 100 pixels high, the body should be 800, not 1000... Though, at this point it may be worth it to just adopt. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Perhaps you can use nested flexbox or even with calc() if needed.

Comment: Hmmm, possibly. I'll give them a go. Thanks!